# Highcharts custom tooltip get pattern legend

Tags: design-patterns, highcharts, tooltip

So I have a chart with series displayed using pattern and gradients.

I also have a custom HTML tooltip along the way.

[image]

I would like to being able to display the legend within the tooltip.

Is there a convenient way to achieve this? I found out that `point.color.toString()` returns something like `url(#highcharts-xxx)` and thought maybe it would be usable but it doesn't work :(

Any chance on that? Besides having to create my own SVG in there, which would be a pain...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @ppotaczek for helping me, this helped me find a solution:

```
<template>
  <td class="px-1">
    <div class="legend">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%">
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" :fill="row.color.toString()"></rect>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </td>
</template

<style>
.legend {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 1rem;
}
</style>
```

So finally I do use the `url(#highcharts-xxx)`, it's just that it is in the SVG format.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use SVG, but it is really easy with Highcharts. Simple example below:

```
const fill = chart.series[0].area.attr('fill');

chart.renderer.rect(10, 10, 100, 100).attr({
    fill
}).add();
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/20f3sjk6/

**API Reference:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/fill

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#rect

Comment: Thanks, you did put me on the right track but this would not have been the final solution as my tooltip is logically outside the chart, so I can't their legend it with absolute coordinates from the chart.

Comment: Hi @Augustin Riedinger, You can use independent SVG drawing. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/pv1znoyg/